# Best practice for result values when returning an error in Go

Tags: go

If your function returns both a value type and also an error type, is it "the go way" to make sure the value type is niled/zero-valued when the error type is non-nil?

Example:

```
func mayError() ([]string, error) {
  ...
}
```

Should the `[]string` return value be `nil` if the `error` is not `nil`?

Comment: Depends on your use case. If you read any go code at all, you'll usually see `return nil, err`, but the non-nil case also does exist.

Comment: @JimB can you give an example of where the non-nil case does exist?

Comment: io.Readers often return a non-zero number and io.EOF, for instance.

Comment: @GeorgeAristy Some APIs document non-zero return values on error. io.Reader and io.Writer are two common examples.

Comment: @GeorgeAristy anytime your function has a non-nilable type as its first return argument, that function is not able to return nil in case of an error.

Comment: @GeorgeAristy: the `http.Client` returns a non-nil response body if `CheckRedirect` fails. The point is if you choose to not follow the norms, make sure it's documented.

Comment: @mkopriva right - but we just use zero values instead in those cases. Anyway, I think Peter and ThunderCat have given good examples of when it is appropriate to return non-nil result values in case of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if a function failed to complete a task, its return value should be treated as unreliable. Because errors in go are values, the caller may ignore the error it returns. For exmaple:

```
foo := myType{
    Bar: 123,
    Foo: "some string",
}

b, _ := json.Marshal(foo)
```

I'm ignoring the error because it's a type I've created, and I know it can be marshalled. However, it's considered bad practice either way. All the same, now imagine someone calling your function:

```
slice, _ := mayError()
```

And your function, after adding 2 elements to the slice, errors. Returning the partial slice could, and probably will, lead to buggy behaviour further down the line. That makes code hard to debug. On balance, I'd say it's best to return a nil slice and an error in that case. If the code looks like this:

```
slice, _ := mayError() // returns nil, someErr
// panic
if slice[0] != "" {
}
```

At least the error shows up immediately, and you'll see any errors returned by `mayError` are being ignored. This makes the code way easier to debug/maintain/fix.

Comment: This is pretty opinion-based, but to me there's little point to defend your API from completely foolish consumers. "If you make something idiot-proof, someone will just make a better idiot." If somebody doesn't error check, that's on them; the function signature makes it clear that they should be checking errors.

Comment: @Adrian: Given the vagueness of the question, though, I can't give a clear-cut answer about the OP's specific situation. I'm working on a codebase right now that contains 1 function that returns value + error. Based on the arguments further up the call chain, and the specific error being returned I might actually use the values still. There can be a valid use-case for this kind of stuff, but I find myself doing this maybe once/year

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am selecting yours as the answer; however, it just raises more questions pretty much along the lines of Adrian's thinking.